# is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed

Tags: qt-creator

I'm trying to finish the assignment 1 for CS106B. But after downloading this project, I found that it can't run properly on Qt Creator. The error messages after compilation are as follows.

D:\Qt project\Assignment 1\src\GUI\GUIUtils.cpp:1: In file included from ..\Assignment 1\src\GUI\GUIUtils.cpp:1:
In file included from ..\Assignment 1\src\GUI\GUIUtils.cpp:1:
..\Assignment 1\src\GUI\GUIUtils.h:66:5: note: 'TextRender::TextRender()' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
66 |     TextRender() = default;
|     ^~~~~~~~~~

And here is the relevant code block:

```
class TextRender {
public:
    /* Bounding rectangles for the text render. The first option gives the bounds that were
     * provided at construction, which is useful if you want to make use of the full space
     * available. The second is the bounding rectangle for where the text will actually
     * draw, which is useful if you want to, say, draw a background behind just the part
     * used.
     */
    GRectangle bounds() const;
    GRectangle computedBounds() const;

    /* Intended font and actual font. */
    MiniGUI::Font font() const;
    MiniGUI::Font computedFont() const;

    /* Draws this text render in the specified window. */
    void draw(GWindow& window);
    void draw(GCanvas* canvas);

    /* Changes the horizontal text alignment. */
    void alignLeft();
    void alignCenterHorizontally();

    /* Changes the vertical text alignment. */
    void alignTop();
    void alignCenterVertically();

    /* Lays out a string to fit within the specified rectangle. The text might not fill up the
     * entirety of that rectangle if it isn't long enough.
     *
     * This function will attempt to respect the font size specified in the font string, but may
     * have to shrink the font size to get things to fit.
     */
    static std::shared_ptr<TextRender> construct(const std::string& text,
                                                 const GRectangle& bounds,
                                                 const MiniGUI::Font& font,
                                                 LineBreak breakMode = LineBreak::BREAK_SPACES);

private:
    TextRender() = default;
    GRectangle    mBounds;         // Bounds specified by the user
    GRectangle    mComputedBounds; // Bounds actually occupied.
    MiniGUI::Font mFont;          // Font specified by the user
    MiniGUI::Font mComputedFont;  // Font actually used

    /* Type representing a single line of text. */
    struct TextLine {
        std::string text;
        GPoint      baseline; // Where the baseline is
        double      width;
    };

    std::vector<TextLine> mLines;

    /* Breaks the text apart into lines, shrinking the font until it fits in the given rectangle.
     * Returns true on success.
     */
    bool fitText(const std::vector<std::string>& tokens, LineBreak breakMode);
};
```

How can I make my program run properly?
I would be grateful for all the help you've provided.

Comment: Maybe one of the members does not have a default constructor?